# How to display my detail in correct order using MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have no idea how to query mysql to display the pattern I want. The table store all booking details of customers. A customer may multiple booking from multiple events. And in 1st stage I only want to check  the customer had booking in which event. If customerA booked in event ABC, event XZY, so system will only display:

[image]

instead of list all like below
[image]

This is my Query:

```
$query = "SELECT customer.companyName, customer.contactName, eventinfo.eventTitle,boothAlias,date, testbook.bstatus, testbook.day, testbook.username, bookingID  from eventinfo, testbook, customer where testbook.username=customer.username AND testbook.eventID=eventinfo.eventID
```

What should I do to display event without repeat for a customer?

The flow is like this, Admin will see customer booked in which event.
[image]

Next, Admin click on view detail too see customer booked which booth in the selected event.
[image]

Lastly, Admin click to view booth details to see customer booked which day for the booth.
(Assume event booth will be rent for exhibition for 14days, customer can choose which day to book, 1st 3days, last few days or in the middle)
[image]

Comment: How does GROUP BY help him to solve the problem?????

Comment: @bensiu Group by will not help him.

Comment: if I GROUP BY eventID, only display the events for a customer, other customers cannot show up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT customer.companyName, customer.contactName, GROUP_CONCAT(eventinfo.eventTitle ) 
from eventinfo, testbook, customer 
where testbook.username=customer.username AND testbook.eventID=eventinfo.eventID
group by customer.companyName, customer.contactName
```

If I understand your problem correctly, this will return you the desired list, but events will be comma seperated

Answer (score 1):

You can't in the database.

You will need to do that in the display application.

Databases work on entire rows at once. Data in a second row has no knowledge of anything in the row before it, so you can't hide the repeat without a lot of very complicated work.

Comment: mean that after call query I need to use for loop to customise the display pattern?

Comment: @mcheng Yes, basically. `$old_customer_id = 0; for(query...) { if($old_customer_id != $customer_id) { output_name; $old_customer_id = $customer_id; } output_other_data }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it in PHP, like Ariel said. Something like this:

```
$current = '';
foreach($result as $row){
  echo '<tr>'
  if ($current != $row->companyName) {
    $current = $row->companyName;
    echo "<td>$row->companyName</td>";
  }
  else echo '<td></td>';

  echo "<td>$row->contactName</td><td>$row->eventTitle</td>"; //etc...
  echo '</tr>';
}
```

This will work only for the companyName field, but should give you an idea how to format it. Make sure you order your query by those columns!